# What is the sock that fierljeppers wear?

Tags: equipment, fierljeppen

[Fierljeppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fierljeppen) wear a something like a sock on one foot, apparently to help with climbing the pole.  What is this called?

Comment: I found this which suggests it could be made out of old bicycle tyres: https://schooltv.nl/files/user_upload/2003_t_WO_NTR_429130_fierljeppen01.pdf